# Mock axios in a Vue application for frontend testing

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, axios

When testing the frontend of my Vue application, I sometimes want to skip the communication with the API backend.

I came up with the following idea:

- add state in Vuex store: `skipServerCommunication`.
- when `skipServerCommunication = false`: send the axios request as expected
- when `skipServerCommunication = true`: return mocked data

The easy way would be to add an check before every call of `axios.post(...)` or `axios.get(...)`, but I don't want to have to add code in every api function I wrote.
So I thought about using the `interceptors` of axios, but I think it's not possible to stop a request, and just return mocked data, right?

I then thought about wrapping axios, and dynamically returning the real axios instance or a mocked one, which also implements the `.post()`, `.get()` and all the other axios functions based on the Store state. I thought about something like this (I'm working with TypeScript):

```js
import store from '@/vuex-store'

const axios = Axios.create( // real store config );
const axiosMock = {
  get(path: string) {
    if (path == '/test') {
      return Promise.resolve( // mocked data );
    }

    return Promise.resolve(true)
  }
}

class AxiosWrapper {
  get instance() {
    if (store.state.skipServerCommunication) {
      return axiosMock;
    }

    return axios
  }
}

export default new AxiosWrapper();
```

But this solution has some problems:

1. I need to replace all axios calls with `axiosWrapper.instance.get(...)`. Can I somehow avoid this and mock axios in a way that I can still work with `axios.get(...)`?
2. VSCode isn't able to provide autocompletion anymore because the returned instance is either of type [`AxiosStatic`](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/4b3947aa59aaa3c0a6187ef20d1b9dddb9bbf066/index.d.ts#L149) or `"MyMockType"`. So I thought about implementing the `AxiosStatic` interface, but I struggle to do that correctly because of the two anonymous functions in the [`AxiosInstance`](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/4b3947aa59aaa3c0a6187ef20d1b9dddb9bbf066/index.d.ts#L130) interface. Is there an alternative way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`axios-mock-adapter`](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter) instead. You can mock `axios` calls as needed per test, using advanced matching patterns.

*Example usage:*

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter'

describe('UserList', () => {
  it('gets users on mount', async () => {
    const mock = new MockAdapter(axios)
    mock.onGet('/users').reply(200, {
      users: [{ id: 1, name: 'John Smith' }],
    })

    const wrapper = shallowMount(UserList)
    await wrapper.find('.getUsersBtn').trigger('click')
    expect(wrapper.vm.users[0].id).toBe(1)
  })
})
```

Comment: That's the thing: I'm not in any test environment but in production! I want my application to mock the data when a certain condition is met during the "real" execution. In other words: I want to be in charge whether an axios call is really made or just some mocked data is returned.

Comment: And you could still do that with `axios-mock-adapter`. It can be used outside a test environment, although I find it odd to be testing in production.

Comment: I'm not testing anything. In certain circumstances (while in "demo" mode) I explicitly want to just return mocked data instead of calling the real API.

Comment: So is it possible to just mock axios on the fly based on a state from Vuex?